# spring.net view the cacheresult for troubleshooting

Tags: caching, spring.net, spring-aop

Howdi folks, 
How can I view the cacheresult of a Spring.NEt AOP caching configuration to see if the cache has the correct results?  Is there a logging feature that I missed? I'm a little new to the fraemwork, so a little detail would be userful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 solutions :
1) Activate the Spring logs at DEBUG level
2) Access the ICache instance used by the Cache attributes, and use the ICache.Keys properties.

```
foreach(object key in ((ICache)context.GetObject("MyCacheId")).Keys)
{
  Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```